# Return handled Exception

Tags: python-3.x

I don't understand why my program is not returning a json response with a error code i defined in a try catch block.

```
json = request.json
return jsonify(controller.new_configuration(json))
```

This is my function new_configuration in Controller.py

```
def new_configuration(self, data):

    try:
        self.config.read('system/settings.ini')
        self.config.set('service_configuration', 'servid', data['servID'])
        self.config.set('service_configuration', 'uri', data['uri'])
        self.config.set('service_configuration', 'res_temp_min', data['res_temp_min'])

        for param in data['modelParameters']:
            self.config.set('model_param', param['k'], param['v'])

        with open('system/settings.ini', 'w') as configfile:
            self.config.write(configfile)

    except TypeError as e:
        return {"rc": 1, "rcDesc": e}
    except ValueError as e:
        return {"rc": 1, "rcDesc": e}
    except KeyError as e:
        self.log.warning(e)
        return {"rc": 1, "rcDesc": e}
    except AttributeError as e:
        self.log.warning(e)
        return {"rc": 1, "rcDesc": e}

    return {"rc": 0, "rcDesc": "ok"}
```

Im sending deliberately a TypeError json and i guess it should be returning {"rc": 1, "rcDesc": e} but it's not.
I got this error instead and the app breaks:

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: KeyError('servID',) is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: What is unclear in error message you have received? What would you expect an Exception instance to be serialized to?

Comment: you should probably surround `jsonify` with a `try/except` block... it looks like this function throws the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the type of `e` is some sort of error, which you cannot serialize as JSON

try:

```
return {"rc": 1, "rcDesc": repr(e)}
```

Also catching all those errors individually might not be necessary, depending on what you are doing

Comment: That worked! It's supposed to work as an api response. I want to return a error code and a description.